# Firebase order by child returning results that do not have the child

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase data structure like the following for direct message chats:

```
{
  "dms" : {
    "meta" : {
      "1-2" : {
        "lastMessage" : "Inadvertently",
        "lastMessageFrom" : 5,
        "lastMessageKey" : "-KhUHUqK9WfUJcjs2fQ-",
        "timestamp" : 1491952336485,
        "users" : {
          "uid-1" : {
            "lastMessageRead" : {
              "key" : "-KhStVBVIfRGepiWt6cn"
            }
          },
          "uid-2" : {
            "lastMessageRead" : {
              "key" : "-KhSrksAgg_2TqmcLjsz"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If the user id is `1`, I only want to retrieve nodes where `users.uid-1` exists. In Swift, I thought this looked like:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("dms").child("meta").queryOrdered(byChild: "users/uid-3").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
...
```

but that is returning every `dms` node. For example, I am querying for `uid-3` above but it will return the node in the data structure example I provided. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding one more child level to the observer? ```...child("users").queryOrdered(byChild:"uid-3").observe...```

Comment: @Prientus Wouldn't that give me the users node in the results? I need the node starting at `1-2` as the key so I get the `lastMessage...` metadata. Also "users" is not a child of "meta" so I'm not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my structure to this:

```
{
  "meta" : {
    "1-2" : {
      "lastMessage" : "Dude....",
      "lastMessageFrom" : 2,
      "lastMessageKey" : "-KhXpXDn7et6mgFJRkWb",
      "timestamp" : 1492011852859,
      "users" : {
        "uid-1" : true,
        "uid-2" : true
      },
      "users-meta" : {
        "uid-2" : {
          "lastMessageRead" : {
            "key" : "-KhXpXDn7et6mgFJRkWb"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my query to require that the child value equal true. I guess in their docs when they explain how null values will be ordered first, they mean null or missing?